# Javascript (WebdriverIO) - casting shadow-element(JSpath) into WebElement

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I have a shadow-root element I can view in my browser console. ex:

```
document.querySelector(".class").shadowRoot.querySelector(".button")
```

In Java(Selenium Webdriver), I was able to use Selenium click command using something like:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
WebElement el = (WebElement) js.executeScript("return document.querySelector(".class").shadowRoot.querySelector(".button")");
el.click();
```

In Javascript(WebdriverIO), I can click the same element using execute() and appending click() to the JSpath:

```
browser.execute (document.querySelector(".class").shadowRoot.querySelector(".button").click();)
```

But I want to to know if there's an alternative to this Javascript click. Is it possible to convert the JSpath to a WebElement just like I did in Java?
I want to utilize WebdriverIO's browser.click(selector) method. I tried:

```
var obj = browser.execute (return document.querySelector(".class").shadowRoot.querySelector(".button"))
var el = browser.elements (obj); //how to convert???
browser.click(el);
```

I also saw others that use $(selector).shadow$(selector). But I want to try using my original JSpath(document.querySelector...).

Comment: Why the Java tag?

Answer (score 0):

I've given up trying to make this work.
I read that Javascript is a weakly typed language (it allows users to use different types of values without using explicit typecasting). And that it only supports explicit conversion to string, to boolean, or to number. I'm guessing typecasting to WebElement can't be done here.